# ID this plant from an inherited garden

Tags: identification

I recently inherited a garden on my university campus in Buffalo, New York. We think that it's a fruiting plant, but we're not sure what it is. Can anyone help?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Stephie oh yeah, wow. I was in the sun with my phone when I took this. I couldn't see how bad it was, I'll get some more when I can

Comment: Always good questions from @Throsby  Is the campus garden?

Comment: @kevinsky Yep! The reason we think it's a fruit-plant (it's not really a bush, not really a vine, we're not sure) is because there's some blueberries off to the right and some raspberries on either side! The rows you can see have beans and peas! It's going to be full garden this year! It's been pretty bad in years past!

Comment: I'd say it's not likely a weed, and the next six months should help clear up details; but better pictures might clear them up faster. Has it flowered already, or are there flower buds?

Comment: I added some photos!

Comment: Any blossoms yet? If so, can we expect new photos?

Comment: Hi Throsby! Any chance it has buds or flowers yet? I'm in Massachusetts and think you might be a little bit cooler, so it might be too soon. Don't want to be a pest, I'm just intrigued and thought we might be getting closer to an identification! I also like tags so people can find things and am waiting to add vine, shrub, or something else when the time comes. :)

Comment: Hiya, sorry about that. Sadly, there haven't been ANY flowers or buds on it at all so far as we've seen. We're right near Buffalo, NY and we've been experiencing some crazy drought and that area in particular is in an open (and very hot) field. I should give an update with photos though, to show its growth

Comment: Did you see it in the spring? My first thought was a forsythia, by the bark appearance, but the leaves aren't serrated. It could be related to one, though.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go with my first impression...GARDENIA...not at all sure of the variety.  Most of the pictures even looked like the nitrogen deficiency inherent in Gardenia leaves.[Gardenia pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=gardenia&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=533&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzjqXy8-HMAhUJnJQKHfuNB34QiR4IqQE&dpr=1.5http://)

Comment: Alrighty, the leaves do look very similar. I'll wait until it flowers to confirm your answer

Comment: COOL.  Make sure to watch for other answers on this site as well.  Bamboo, Kevinsky and Steph will most certainly be giving you answers and they are very good.  A larger picture of the buds would help especially the flowering buds.  Don't fertilize it with lots of Nitrogen or you might not get flowers for quite awhile.  You could prune that long stem off above the majority of those leaves to hurry up the process as well.  But wait for the others to answer, grins!!

Comment: I don't think a Gardenia would have survived a Buffalo winter. :( I too think that this looks like some sort of fruiting shrub. I just can't put my finger on it. Flowers will definitely help. A wild guess by me would be Haskap (Lonicera caerulea).

Comment: Oh my bad...duh, didn't read the location.  Nope but it kinda does look gardeniaish, grins.  I don't know Haskap...I'll go check this guy out I love lonicera genus.

Comment: Nice guess.  The leaves look too thin?  The photo by the OP shows thicker leaves of an evergreen broadleaf thing.  Which would be tough in Buffalo for sure. Never heard of this plant...nice...Lonicera caerulea, sounds wide spread but is it in the pacific northwest?

Comment: I believe there are variants that are in the Pacific NW range. They're becoming a more and more popular food crop up here in Canada, noted for their high nutrition and antioxidant properties (berries). Again, it was a stab-in-the-dark. I know I know this plant but I can't put my finger on it with certainty. Yet. :)